# How can I prevent two sounds from playing simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, audio, expo

In my app, I have two pressable places, and if you press one of them, it plays the corresponding sound.
And, if you press the other one, of course, it plays the corresponding sound.

But I want something like this: when one is being played, if I press the other one, the previous one will be stopped playing, rather than playing two of them at the same time, how can I do that?

Here is my code.
These two are pressable:

```js
<SoundPlayer voice={route.params.voice}>
  <English English={route.params.English} />
</SoundPlayer>

<SoundPlayer voice={route.params.voice2}>
  <NoteDesc noteDesc={route.params.noteDesc} />
</SoundPlayer>
```

This is for playing sounds:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

export default function SoundPlayer({ voice, children }) {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    if (sound) {
      console.log("Unloading Sound");
      await sound.unloadAsync();
    }
    const { sound: newSound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(voice);
    setSound(newSound);

    console.log("Playing Sound");
    await newSound.playAsync();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log("Unloading Sound");
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  English: {
    color: "snow",
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this `sound` state in `SoundPlayer`. It will be unique to each `<SoundPlayer />`  call. So at this point, whenever `playSound` is called, `sound`  refers only to the current component's playing sound.

I would suggest you move this `const [sound, setSound] = useState()` in an outer parent component, for example with the [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context). Something like this:

```
// SoundContextProvider.js

import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const SoundContext = createContext();

export default function SoundContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState();
  return <SoundContext.Provider value={{ sound, setSound }}>{children}</SoundContext.Provider>;
}

export function useSoundContext() {
  return useContext(SoundContext);
}
```

Grab it inside `SoundPlayer` like below. This way you are always referring to the same `sound` instance:

```
import { useSoundContext } from "./SoundContextProvider"; // Make sure you use the correct path.

export default function SoundPlayer({ voice, children }) {
  const { sound, setSound } = useSoundContext();

  // ...
}
```

Finally, ensure, for example, in `App.js`, you render your components wrapped by `SoundContextProvider`:

```
import SoundContextProvider from "./SoundContextProvider"; // Make sure you use the correct path.
export default function App() {
  // ...
  return <SoundContextProvider>{/* Your components goe here*/}</SoundContextProvider>;
}
```

Comment: Wow this beautifully worked!! I spent like 6 hours trying to solve this but no progress...I was almost giving up, but you literally saved me! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad I could give the hint @sahasrabhujaneuron. Have a good day!